# MVC 4 How to process a url parameter on every page, base controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Looking for some guidance in designing my new MVC 4 app.

I would like to have a url parameter `s=2011` on every page of the app to let me know what year of data I'm working with. Obviously, the user will have a way to change that parameter as needed.

I will need that parameter in every controller and wondering the best way to do this. I was thinking of creating a base controller that reads `Request.QueryString` and puts the year into a public property. However, considering all the extensability points in MVC, I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This very much depends on the design of your app, but just to give you two alternatives

**`IActionFilter`**

If you are doing data context per request you can use a global `IActionFilter` to hook pre-action execution globally and apply a query filter to your data context behind the scenes.

Major down-side of this is that to test the controller you will need to have the full MVC pipeline setup so that the actionfilter gets applied properly.

**Dependency Injection**

Instead of using sub-classing (base controller as you say) you can use dependency injection . Keeping things more loose will allow you to pull the filter from query string, cookie, user setting in the database or whatever else - without your controller knowing where it comes from.

Here is some pseudo code how I would do it if I was using something like Entity Framework or Nhibernate (also I am sure applicable with other technologies as well)

```
public Car
{
    public string Year { get; set; }
}

public class CarsDataContext : DbContext
{
    private IQuerable<Cars> _cars = null;
    private Func<Car, bool> _carsFilter = null;

    public IQuerable<Car> Cars {
        get {
            if (_carsFitler != null)
                return _cars.Where(_carsFitler);

            return _cars;
        } 
        set { _cars = value; }
    }

    public void ApplyCarsFilter(Func<Car, bool> predicate)
    {
        _carsFilter = predicate;
    }
}
```

Assuming you have dependency injection setup already (NInject or whichever other framework) in you can configure how the context to be intialized

```
Bind<CarsDataContext>().ToMethod(() => {
    string yearFilter = GetYearFilter(); // can be coming from anywhere

    CarsDataContext dataContext = new CarsDataContext();
    dataContext.Applyfilter(car => car.Year == yearFilter);
    return dataContext;
}).InRequestScope();
```

Then my controller knows nothing about the data filtering and I can easily test it:

```
class MyController : Controller
{
    public MyController(CarsDataContext dataContext)
    {
    }
    ...
}
```

However I would only do this is filtering the dataset was across many controllers and important part of my software. Otherwise it's pure over-engineering.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I've built and registered an IActionFilter which pulls out the url parameter. But how do I get that data back into my controller?

Comment: I didn't expand on the IActionFilter, because I am not convinced it's the way to go and as I mentioned in my answer I would probably go towards the second option.

Comment: I'm not using it to filter my dataset like you showed in the DI description. I need to have the value of that parameter available in many - if not all - of the controllers. Maybe subclass the controller and use DI to inject the parameter? But I don't believe the base class has the HttpContext. (Do appreciate the help!)

Comment: filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.Session = s; not loving it.